# How to use my RapidMiner .model in my unity3d/visual studio for android platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rapidminer

I have created an iris model and I want to use it in my Unity android platform. How can I call and make predictions with the model I referenced using C# code?

Comment: Rapidminer doesn't have a .NET SDK, so you will need to write a native plugin. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

Comment: @LeoBartkus thank you very much! Noted.